# Creating numeric directories in C

Tags: c, numeric

I'm trying to create a set of numerical directories in C. But doesn't work... I was hoping to see:

```
\Directory 0
\Directory 1
.
.
.
\Directory 99
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <conio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
    char istring[80];

    for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    {
        sprintf(istring, "Directory %i", n);
        mkdir(istring);
    }
}
```

Yes i know the directory will / should be created locally, but it is not. I have also searched the c drive for the "\Directory n" directory, but there are none.

Using:

```
sprintf(istring, "\\Directory %i", n);
```

Doesn't create a directory in root.

To check privileges, i've tried this:

```
mkdir("Directory n");
```

A local directory is created \Directory n. So i am assuming I have enough privilages.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try break-pointing and one-stepping in the debugger of your IDE? Did you check the return values of the system functions which you call? For instance mkdri() returns some pretty specific info as to why it failed - it could probably tell you more than we could ;-)  For GNU, see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-Directories.html, for others, like Windows, see your relevant documentation

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Your program **does not compile** (which IMO invalidates the entire question), but after fixing the obvious errors, it works as you seem to intend and I get 100 new folders inside the folder from where I ran it.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post. I will ensure I only post a question where I have compiled the code and not just taken bits. Sorry. R

Comment: Well, does it work after making it work correctly? It does for me, so your problem is "not reproducible".

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get it to work. It was a small code error and permissions on windows 8. Thanks for your help. R

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify an absolute path. The way you wrote it the program would create the directories in the path where it was running from.

If you wanted to create the directories in the root path, you'd have to change it to:

```
sprintf(istring, "\\Directory %i", n);
```

But most likely you'd need elevated privileges to do that.

Most likely you're not looking in the right path for the created directories..

Comment: Yes i know the directory would be created locally (where the .exe sits).

Comment: @Rowlandski Not where the exe sits, where it is run from.  The cwd a.k.a. $PWD ... Use getcwd().